# How to display btrfs subvolume tree?

Tags: btrfs, tree

Is there a way to make a btrfs subvolume tree like what is shown below?  (Only subvolumes - no regular directories or files.)

```
# tree /mnt/1
/mnt/1
├── a
├── snapshot
│   ├── a
│   └── subv
└── subv
    └── b
```

This example is created from a "sample" btrfs with no regular directories or files.
`tree <mountpoint>` shows all directories and files, not just the subvolumes.  Using the `-d` option shows only directories, which is better, but still shows non-subvolume directories.

So, on an installed system, you get:

```
# tree /
/
├── bin -> usr/bin
├── boot
│   ├── grub
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   │   └── unicode.pf2
│   │   ├── grub.cfg
│   │   ├── grub.cfg.example
│   │   ├── grubenv
│   │   ├── i386-pc
│   │   │   ├── 915resolution.mod
│   │   │   ├── acpi.mod
│   │   │   ├── adler32.mod
│   │   │   ├── affs.mod
... <over 242,000 lines snipped>
```

Comment: How about `tree -x`? It's not exactly what you asked for, but it may suit your purpose.

Comment: `btrfs subvolume list /` currently gives me 10 lines.   `tree -x /` gives me over 108,000 lines.

Comment: Yeah, so then that's no good :-( I guess the trouble with your requirement is the question of what such a command should show if subvolumes `/a` and `/a/b/c` exist but the intermediate `/a/b` is not a subvolume but a regular directory. Omit the second level in the tree? But then where would `/a/z` appear if `/a/z` were a subvolume? Or show a blank placeholder in place of `/a/b` which isn't a subvolume? Also seems problematic. Anyway, maybe I'm just not imaginative enough to see the solution. Good luck.

Comment: @Celada - When I run `btrfs subvolume list /`, I see ID ### gen ### top level ### path <path>.  Is the top level number corresponding to the ID numbers?  If so, I'd be happy for a tree generated on that basis, where top level 5 (at least on my system, indicating the "top-level" subvolumes) are shown, with recursive branches showing any subvolumes with that node's top level.  I'm guessing it would probably have to be a btrfs-progs feature.

Comment: I'm working on putting together [a script for this](https://github.com/etskinner/svtree). So far I've populated objects of each subvolume in a btrfs file system with their children. Anyone who's interested in helping please feel free to submit a pull request.

Comment: @etskinner - are you still working on svtree.py? I tried it and did not get expected output.

Comment: @MountainX-for-Monica Apologies, I abandoned it before getting it to a fully working state

Answer (score 5):

See this solution. It gets the list of subvols from `btrfs` command, strips the paths' column only, then passes through 2 tools: 1st converts path list to hierarchically indented text, 2nd adds ascii art tree in the place of indentation.

`btrfs subvol list / | cut -f9 -d' ' | sed -e 's/^/ROOT\//' | paths2indent | indent2tree`

You find these 2 perl scripts here: [paths2indent](https://github.com/bAndie91/tools/blob/master/usr/bin/paths2indent) and [indent2tree](https://github.com/bAndie91/tools/blob/master/usr/bin/indent2tree)

Example subvol list:

```
ID 1883 top level 5 path slash
ID 2004 top level 5 path logs
ID 2005 top level 5 path dbase
ID 2006 top level 5 path sdata
ID 2007 top level 5 path users
ID 2937 top level 5 path slash/snaps/by-procedure/quota-yazzy/users
ID 2938 top level 5 path slash/snaps/by-date/2019-11-21_0100/dbase
ID 2939 top level 5 path slash/snaps/by-date/2019-11-21_0100/slash
ID 2940 top level 5 path slash/snaps/by-date/2019-11-21_0100/logs
ID 2941 top level 5 path slash/snaps/by-date/2019-11-21_0100/sdata
ID 3004 top level 5 path slash/snaps/home/2019-12-04_0600
```

Example output:

```
ROOT
├── dbase
├── slash
│   └── snaps
│       ├── by-procedure
│       │   └── quota
│       │       └── users
│       ├── by-date
│       │   └── 2019-11-21_0100
│       │       ├── dbase
│       │       ├── slash
│       │       ├── sdata
│       │       └── logs
│       └── home
│           └── 2019-12-04_0600
├── users
├── sdata
└── logs
```

**EDIT**: newer versions output format differ, so change `cut`'s field number if needed (`-f7` vs. `-f9`).

Comment: Can you check that this is still working? It is not working for me, even after this fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59889217/463994

Comment: Resolved: I just needed to change the cut parameter to `-f9`

Comment: The links to your helper scripts are broken. They're here now: [indent2tree](https://github.com/bAndie91/tools/blob/master/user-tools/indent2tree) [paths2indent](https://github.com/bAndie91/tools/blob/master/user-tools/paths2indent)